# The set of irreducible representations (over C) determines a finite group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm trying to understand group representations, and I think that this statement is correct (where *determines* means *up to isomorphism*), although I couldn't find a proof online (without references to more complicated things like "Tannaka duality"), so I tried to prove it, but I may have overlooked something:

Let $G = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$, $H = \{y_1, ..., y_n\}$ be two finite groups of same cardinality.

Suppose G and H have the same set of irreducible representations in the following sense :
there is a finite set of morphisms $g_i$ (resp. $h_i$), each one from G (resp. H) to
some subgroup of $GL(n_i, \Bbb{C})$ and we can write $g_i(x_j) = P_i h_i(y_j) P_i^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P_i$ and all $j$.

Then if we consider the regular representation of G, we can write it as a sum of the $g_i$ representations
(with $n_i$ giving the multiplicity) and do the same for H.

That shows that the two regular representations are isomorphic as we can build a new base using a block-diagonal transition matrix using $(P_i)$.
As they are also faithful (isomorphic to the groups themselves), then G and H are isomorphic.

Is that correct ?

EDIT: I updated the "same set of irreducible representations" following the comments (that also requires the additional assumption of same cardinality)

Comment: "for some invertible matrix $P_i$ and all $(x,y) \in G\times H$" is surely wrong. [Eg with $x\not=1$, $y=1$.]

Comment: I think that in order to have any hope of proving this properly you need to first say exactly what you mean by "$G$ and $H$ have the same set of irreducible representations (over ${\mathbb C}$)". A representation is a homomorphism from $G$ to a general linear group, so representations of $G$ and $H$ can only be formally equal if $G=H$. If you mean they have same set of images of irreducible representations then the result is not true, because that would apply to $G=C_2$ and $H=C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: It's much harder than this to make precise what it means for $G$ and $H$ to have "the same" irreducible representations. The obvious ways to write down a correct formal definition already require $G$ and $H$ to be isomorphic. If you want to do better than that you really do need to get into the muck of Tannaka duality.

Comment: Well I suppose that you could assume that we are given a bijection between $G$ and $H$ with respect to which which the representations are equal, and then use this to prove that the bijection is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency in the previous definition of "same set of irreducible representations", I updated the statement.

Comment: @Weier: it's confusing to write $g_i$ and $h_i$ for representations instead of elements of the groups $G$ and $H$. You haven't said anything about them being irreducible, but can I assume you intend for the $g_i$ and $h_i$ to be an enumeration of the irreducible representations of $G$ and $H$ respectively?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree it's confusing...
And yes, the g_i and h_i should be an enumeration of the irreducible representations of their respective groups (one representant of each equivalence class).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan something else that is confusing is that I labeled the groups elements with 1...n as if it was arbitrary, whereas in fact this labelling is part of the "same set of irreducible representations" definition (in my view, it corresponds to the bijection Derek was talking about).
I'll rewrite it all if their is no flaw in the reasoning.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Once you make the bijection explicit you're asking for a bijection $f : G \to H$ such that matrix representatives $\rho_{G, i} : G \to GL_{n_i}(\mathbb{C}), \rho_{H, i} : H \to GL_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ of the irreducible representations can be chosen such that we always have $\rho_{G, i}(g) = \rho_{H, i}(f(g))$ (you can absorb the matrices $P_i$ into $\rho_{H, i}$). This forces $f$ to be an isomorphism, so... you might as well not talk about the irreducible representations and just check that the $f$ you want is an isomorphism!

Comment: The interesting thing about Tannaka duality is that it gives you a way of saying "$G$ and $H$ are isomorphic if they have the same representation theory" which doesn't require starting out with such a bijection but actually constructs it out of other data.

Answer (score 1):

Your theorem is correct: we can reconstruct a group's operation from a full set of irreducible representations (interpreted as mere functions from $G$ to $GL(V)$s). And your proof is also correct: we can reconstruct the regular representation (as a function) by taking direct sums of the irreps (with multiplicities equal to their dimensions); then $G$ is isomorphic to its image (under the regular rep) so its operation can be recovered by transporting matrix multiplication back to it.

We can probably phrase this in categorical terms, by considering the category whose objects are $(X,\mathcal{F})$ where $X$ is a set of $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of functions on $X$, and whose morphisms are tuples $(\alpha,\beta,\Phi)$ where $\Phi$ is a family of functions $\phi_f$ indexed by $\mathcal{F}$, and $\alpha:X\to Y,\beta:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ satisfy the diagram $f=\phi_f\circ\beta(f)\circ\alpha$.

Given a group $G$, we can construct such an object as $(G,\mathcal{F})$ with $\mathcal{F}$ a complete set of irreducible representations, then any isomorphism $(G_1,\mathcal{F}_1)\to(G_2,\mathcal{F}_2)$ with $\Phi$ consisting of linear operators can be converted into an isomorphism $G_1\to G_2$.

---

Remiss to not explain why Tannaka-Krein duality (a) is natural and (b) not that complicated for finite groups. First of all, just as every (finite-dimensional) vector space is (not naturally) isomorphic to its dual, every (finitely-generated) abelian group is (not naturally) isomorphic to its dual, aka its character group. However, the dual *of* the dual *is* naturally isomorphic in these cases. Indeed, the Pontryagin dual of the Pontryagin dual of a locally compact abelian group is naturally isomorphic to the original group. This is achieved with the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is self-dual) or between $S^1$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (which are dual).

The question, then, is if we can generalize this to nonabelian $G$. The characters of an abelian group are its irreps, and pointwise multiplying characters is equivalent to tensoring them. Can we recover a finite group (or more generally, a compact group, if not locally compact) from its irreducible representation and tensor product? The first issue is that irreps are not closed under tensoring, so (being category theorists as well as represenation theorists) we consider the monoidal category of representations of $G$ with the tensor product operation. This turns out to not be enough, but it is if we equip it with the fiber functor $\Phi$ (forgetful functor to the category of vector spaces).

Then $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)\cong G$ (tensor-preserving natural functors). Pick a $v\in V$ and consider evaluation-at-$v$ as a morphism $\mathbb{C}[G]\to V$ given by $x\mapsto xv$, to show $\eta\in\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)$ satisfies $\eta_V(v)=\eta_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(e)v$, then consider the "comultiplication" morphism $\Delta:\mathbb{C}[G]\to\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes\mathbb{C}[G]$ given by $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$ to show $\eta_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(e)=g$ for some group element $g$. Then $\eta\leftrightarrow g$ is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)\cong G$.

There is still "duality" present here. All intertwiners intertwine with all $\pi_V(g)$ operators, and conversely the natural transformations which intertwine with all intertwiners are precisely of the form $\eta_V=\pi_V(g)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "correct" way to deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, without requiring bijection between the two group is the following.

Define a *straightening system* $\mathcal{S}$ as a finite collection of vector spaces  $V_0, \ldots, V_n$ over $\mathbb{C}$, equipped with an hermitian product, of dimensions $d_0=1, d_1, \ldots, d_n$, plus the following data:

- Numbers $n_{ij}^k$ such that
  $$ d_i d_j = \sum_k n_{ij}^k d_k$$
- A permutation $\sigma: \in S_{n+1}$ such that $\sigma(0) = 0$;
- Unitary isomorphisms $T_{ij} : V_i \otimes V_j  \to \oplus_k (V_k) ^{n_{ij}^k} $
- Unitary isomorphisms $\phi_i : V_i \to V_{\sigma(i) }$;

For $W$ a vector space equipped with an hermitian product, let $U(W) $ be the space of unitary automorphisms. Also, for $f: V \to W$ an unitary isomorphism, define
$$E(f) : U(V) \to U(W) $$
Be the conjugation by $f$.
Define the little tannaka group of the straightening system as
$$\tau(\mathcal{S}) := \{ (u_i) \in \prod_i U(V_i) : E(T_{ij}) (u_i \otimes u_j) = \oplus_k n_{ij}^k u_k, E(\phi_i) (u_i) = u_{\sigma(i)} $$

The group structure is given by componentwise multiplication. We have the following

**Proposition**.  *Let $G$ be a group, and let $\mathcal{S}(G) $ be the straightening system defined in this way:

- Vector spaces are the irreducible representations and $V_0$ is the trivial representation, and the hermitian product is the only positive definite invariant by the $G$ action;
- $n_{ij}^k = \langle \chi_i \chi_j, \chi_k \rangle $, where $\chi_s$ is the character of the representation $V_s$;
- The permutation is such that $V_i^* \simeq V_{\sigma(i) }$;
- Isomorphisms $T_{ij}$ are given by the representation isomorphism
  $$ V_i \otimes V_j \simeq_G \oplus_k (V_k) ^{n_{ij}^k}$$
- Isomorphism $\phi_i$ is given by the repn isomorphism
  $$ V_i^* \simeq V_{\sigma(i) }$$

Then the map

$$ G \to \tau(\mathcal{S}(G) ) $$
given by $g \mapsto (\rho_i(g) ) $ is an isomorphism of groups*.

This is not easy to show, but it is true. Let me remark two facts:

- The data of spaces and numbers $n_{ij}^k$ alone does not determine the group structure; one can show that these data are equivalent to give the character table of $G$, which is notoriously not equivalent to give the group;
- The additional data of the isomorphisms are enough to determine the group, and two groups will be isomorphic one to each other iff the two straightening systems are isomorphic. Morally the flexibility you have in the straightening system is the choice of the isomorphism $T_{ij}$; you can multiply this by a constant on each summand $V_k$ of $V_i \otimes V_j$ and it will still be an isomorphism of representations. What the proposition says is that this is the only flexibility you have.

Comment: This is something I proved on my own a few years ago; it's easy if one mimicks the proof of Tannaka duality, but hard without this tool in your backpack.