# Are some irreducible representations redundant?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

I am very new to group theory so it is likely that this question could be very obvious.

I have just completed a question where we find the irreps of $D_4$, which the question defined as a group generated by the two matrices $$ \sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \epsilon = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

After finding the character table, I found that $D_4$ had 4 1D irreps (given below) and 1 2D irrep (just represented by the matrices generated by those above).

$$R_1 = \{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$$
$$R_2 = \{1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1\}$$
$$R_3 = \{1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1\}$$
$$R_4 = \{1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1\}$$.

My question is about the significance of these 5 irreps. It seems to me like the group can be completely represented by its 2D irrep (after all, in my question the group was *defined* just by these matrices) and that the 4 1D irreps provide no additional information. So firstly, am I correct in that these 1D irreps provide no additional information about the group and that it is uniquely defined by its 2D irrep?

Secondly, I am confused by the link between a group's irreps and its representation decomposition. Irreps are often described as the 'fundamental building blocks', but I'm not sure how exactly to interpret them here. Is the point that the group can be represented by a direct sum of these irreps, or a tensor product, or neither? If the former, it still seems like the 1D irreps provide no new information here.

(I have noticed that the -1's in the 1D irreps correspond to the size 2 conjugacy classes of 2D matrices which contain 2 matrices which are -1 $\times$ each other so maybe there is some information there?)

Comment: To answer your final question, every complex representation is equivalent to a direct sum of irreducible representations. None of them are redundant, because that statement would not be true if you left any of them out.

Comment: I guess most of my question can be boiled down to 'what is the point of the 4 1D irreps here since the 2D irrep (which seems to me to be identical to the group) contains all the information'

Comment: My previous comment answers your question. I have no idea what you mean by "contains all the information".

Comment: @DerekHolt so is that just saying that any more complicated representation which wants to represent $D_4$ will always be able to be written as a direct sum of some of these 5 irreps?

Comment: Yes exactly - and of course in the direct sum you can repeat any of the irreducibles as many times as you like.

Comment: Also the irreducible representations to not encode the group uniquely.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Really? If the group here was defined by those 2D matrices, how could the 2D irrep not encode the group uniquely? (Or is this just a special case?)

Comment: @QuantumSpace That's not true. The irreducibles do determine the group - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806072). Perhaps you are thinking of the character table? There are non-isomorphic groups (such as $Q_8$ and $D_8$) with the same character table.

Comment: @DerekHolt and thanks, I think I was considering the 'problem in hand' incorrectly. I think I thought the point of finding the irreps was to find some 'simplest way' of representing the group, so I was confused as to why you would need anything other than the 2D irrep here. However I think now the problem is more 'if we want to create *any* representation of this group (even not very simple), what simpler representations can it be decomposed into. Is this correct?

Comment: @Derek Holt Yes, the irreducibles and how you tensor them. The monoidal structure is essential here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two concepts here. The first is in what sense are the irreducible representations the building blocks of all representations. This, as mentioned in the comments, is because every representation over $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of irreducible representations.

The second, which you are alluding to, is whether, given the $2$-dimensional representation, you need the others. What you seem to be driving at is that the $2$-dimensional representation is *faithful*, meaning the homomorphism to the matrix group is injective. Indeed, the $2$-dimensional representation is faithful, and any faithful representation of $D_4$ must have that $2$-dimensional representation as a summand. In that sense you do not need the other representations to define your group, and the other representations *cannot* be used, in that you always need the $2$-dimensional representation.

A finite group has a faithful, irreducible representation if and only if its centre is cyclic. So for the group $C_2\times C_2$ you cannot find a faithful irreducible representation, and you would need the sum of two of them to produce an isomorphic copy of your group. In general, if the centre needs $n$ elements to generate it, one needs $n$ irreducible representations to be faithful (and of course, you must choose your representations wisely to obtain a faithful representation).

Comment: Amazing, this clears it all up. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. You mentioned, "any faithful representation of 4 must have that 2-dimensional representation as a summand". Is it true for general (finite) group G that any faithful representation must have a faithful irrep as a summand?

Comment: @xiaohuamao No. The Klein four p is an example, as is any non-cyclic abelian group. It is true if the intersection of the kernels of all unfaithful representations is non-trivial, as it is for the $D_8$ case.